# Why vector<int> is faster than vector<bool> in the following case

Tags: c++, vector

This phenomenon is found when I programmed for the LeetCode problem [N-Queens](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/41336615/).

I have two versions of accepted code, the only difference between which is the way I stored the hash table, one is using `vector<int>` and the other is using `vector<bool>`. To be specific, the two versions of code are as follows:

Version 1, `vector<int>`, Running Time: 4 ms

```
class Solution {
public:
void dfs(vector<string>& crtrst, vector<vector<string>>& finalrsts, int row, vector<int>& mup, vector<int>& m45dgr, vector<int>& m135dgr)
{
    int n = crtrst.size();
    
    if (row == n)
    {
        finalrsts.push_back(crtrst);
        return;
    }
    
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (mup[j] && m45dgr[j-row+n-1] && m135dgr[row+j])
        {
            crtrst[row][j] = 'Q';
            mup[j] = m45dgr[j-row+n-1] = m135dgr[row+j] = 0;
        
            dfs(crtrst,finalrsts,row+1,mup,m45dgr,m135dgr);
        
            crtrst[row][j] = '.';
            mup[j] = m45dgr[j-row+n-1] = m135dgr[row+j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

vector<vector<string>> solveNQueens(int n) 
{
    vector<vector<string>> finalrsts;
    vector<string> crtrst(n,string(n,'.'));
    vector<int> mup(n,1);
    vector<int> m45dgr(2*n-1,1); // degree 45: '\'
    vector<int> m135dgr(2*n-1,1); // degree 135: '/';
    int row = 0;
    dfs(crtrst,finalrsts,row,mup,m45dgr,m135dgr);
    return finalrsts;
}
};
```

Version 2, `vector<bool>`, Running time: 12 ms

```
class Solution {
public:
void dfs(vector<string>& crtrst, vector<vector<string>>& finalrsts, int row, 
    vector<bool>& mup, vector<bool>& m45dgr, vector<bool>& m135dgr)
{
    int n = crtrst.size();
    
    if (row == n)
    {
        finalrsts.push_back(crtrst);
        return;
    }
    
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (mup[j] && m45dgr[j-row+n-1] && m135dgr[row+j])
        {
            crtrst[row][j] = 'Q';
            mup[j] = m45dgr[j-row+n-1] = m135dgr[row+j] = false;
        
            dfs(crtrst,finalrsts,row+1,mup,m45dgr,m135dgr);
        
            crtrst[row][j] = '.';
            mup[j] = m45dgr[j-row+n-1] = m135dgr[row+j] = true;
        }
    }
}

vector<vector<string>> solveNQueens(int n) 
{
    vector<vector<string>> finalrsts;
    vector<string> crtrst(n,string(n,'.'));
    vector<bool> mup(n,true);
    vector<bool> m45dgr(2*n-1,true); // degree 45: '\'
    vector<bool> m135dgr(2*n-1,true); // degree 135: '/';
    int row = 0;
    dfs(crtrst,finalrsts,row,mup,m45dgr,m135dgr);
    return finalrsts;
}
};
```

As I know that, `vector<bool>` stores each element using 1 bit rather than a `bool` variable (may be 2 Bytes), and `vector<int>` stores each element using 4 Bytes. So `vector<bool>` seems tinier than `vector<int>`. However, why it is slower than `vector<int>`?

Comment: Intuitively, it takes *time* to pack/unpack a bit from compressed storage, so I would *expect* `std::vector<int>` to outperform `std::vector<bool>`, especially since what the CPU actually works with are registers (`int`-sized or larger).

Comment: May I know what kind of compiler are you using?

Comment: This is a good example as to how programmer intuition is frequently wrong when it comes to predicting performance behaviour.

Comment: @DawidPi, I reported the time according to LeetCode Online Judge. So I don't know what compiler it uses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Access to single bits is usually slower than to complete addressable units (bytes in the lingo of C++). For example, to write a byte, you just issue a write instruction (mov on x86). To write a bit, you need to load the byte containing it, use bitwise operators to set the right bit within the byte, and then store the resulting byte.

The compact size of a bit vector is nice for storage requirements, but it will result in a slowdown except when your data becomes large enough that caching issues play a role.

If you want to have speed and still be more efficient than 4 bytes per value, try a `vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Why `vector<unsigned char>` will be faster than `vector<bool>` ? I tested the differences with my desktop (both `unsigned char` and `bool` evaluated to `1` byte ), result of `vector<bool>` is 3 times slower than `vector<unsigned char>`. I can't figure out the details since both of them are 1 byte.

Comment: No, they're not. Specifically, `vector<bool>` doesn't store each bool as an individual byte; instead it packs them together as bits. That makes it more storage-efficient, but slower. That's the entire point of the question.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation:

There's a `vector<type>` specialization for `bool`, which is a bit map; that's highly efficient with regard to storage (1Byte of vector storage = 8 bool), but worse at actually accessing the data; for any other `vector`, you can just access the element at the `n`th position by `*([address of first element + n * sizeof(element)])`, but for the getting bool-out-of-byte storage, you'll inevitably will need to do some bit operations, which, in times of large caches, might be significantly slower than just having an array of `int`s, representing one truth value each.